# DropDownList showing the SQL value

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have populated a DropDownList with values from an SQL statement and it works.

```
   Try
        cmdStr = "SELECT [idt],[col1] FROM [test];"
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    da.Fill(ds)
                    DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "idt"
                    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "col1"
                    DropDownList1.DataBind()
                End Using
                cmd.Dispose()
                conn.Close()
                conn.Dispose()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        TextBox1.Text = ex.Message
    End Try
```

The problem is the SQL list starts with idt=68 and it shows in the DropDownList as such but DropDownList1.DataTextField="" instead of 68 below.

```
     Try
        cmdStr = "SELECT [datetime],[col1],[col2],[col3] FROM [test] WHERE [idt]=@idt;"
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idt", DropDownList1.DataTextField)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update it to use DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text

```
Try
        cmdStr = "SELECT [datetime],[col1],[col2],[col3] FROM [test] WHERE [idt]=@idt;"
        Using conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idt", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
 DropDownList1.DataTextField = "idt"
 DropDownList1.DataValueField = "idt"
 DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

You don't need to select "col1" column . Because You don't use it.

Then

Use SelectedValue property

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idt", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

check your DataValueField,DataTextField

```
DataValueField=will be id for that field/id whenever your search or do any operation
DataTextField= text for that field/id to show on UI.
```

i guess this would work

```
      DropDownList1.DataTextField = "col1"
      DropDownList1.DataValueField = "idt"
```